# How can I prevent double tap zooming when the absolute view fit to device moves right a few pixel in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added view port meta attribute as follows: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Usually, it works well, but the problem occurs when I use margin-left and thus move the absolute main view to the right, outside of the device view. In this case, when double-tapped, the view becomes zoomed out to contain the whole contents (including the part that is moved outside of the device view).

I don't understand why the view port meta attribute doesn't apply to this case.
Can someone answer this?

Comment: If you could include your markup, CSS and JavaScript if you used any, that would be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a site I was developing. I solved the issue using overflow:hidden on the body for small screen sizes. You may also want to try to use padding instead of margin and mark those elements box-sizing:border-box. Give it a shot and also post your code so I can get a better idea!

All the best,
Shalom